# facebook doesnot recognize url when sharing status

Tags: php, facebook, .htaccess

I have made small script in php what it does is it gets the url and redirects it to another website only domain name changes rest of the url remains same 
here is my code

.htacess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^?]*)$ /index.php?path=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

index.php

```
<?php 
$url = 'http://justfun4funny.com/';
if (isset($_REQUEST['path']))
{
$url.=$_REQUEST['path'];
}

//var_dump($url);
header( "refresh:0;url=$url" ); ?>
<html>
Please wait while article is being loaded
<h1 style="color:blue;font-size:30"><a rel="canonical" href="<?php echo $url ?>">Click Here to Continue</a></h1>
<div style='display:none'>
 <iframe src="<?php echo $url?>"></iframe> 
</div>
</html>
```

the problem i am facing is when i paste this url on my facebook status
http://viralresort.com/2801 
it reads all the data for website including image .
http://viralresort.com/2660
but the above url is not recognized by facebook it shows blank data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi try entering the URL into facebook Debugger.

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fjustfun4funny.com%2F2660

You can also ask Facebook to fetch new information for any URL. I hope this helps.

The debugger is a handy URL, you should keep. Sometimes Information takes time to get cached into facebook. You can additionally add og:type tag to pass information to facebook.

Comment: Thanks bro it really helped me figure out what was the problem.